# I cannot access some sites from my ISP sometimes

Tags: web-hosting, isp

This happens a lot to my own sites that i browse daily from my ISP internet. Most of them are wordpress site. I host in webhosting provided by hostforweb. 
First it opens well and i can login to admin panels and access site for some time. whenever i do some browsing it suddenly stops working. but I can still browse through proxy or other ISP internet. 
I am confused if this is hosting server issue or my ISP issue. when i check status from http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/onnepal.com i can see it is ok and it's just me. Can some one enlighten me on this?

Comment: Have you thought about asking your ISP?

Comment: Yes and they have no idea :( Support here are not that good i think I should try switching ISP

Comment: If your ISP can't support you, that's a pretty clear sign of incompetence.  Switch ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you hinted you'll first need to diagnose if it's a connection issue from your computer or an issue with your ISP.

You say that you can connect to your server via a proxy when you're experiencing difficulties; that would indicate that your ISP isn't stopping you from web browsing. But that doesn't rule out some issue with your server.

I'd first try checking your access logs (if you have access to them) on the web server to see if it is seeing your access attempts from your home computer's IP address.

I'd also try pinging the server to see if you can see the server from the system. Traceroute as well to see if you can establish where the connection is possibly being dropped (although some routers may be dropping packets that are needed to trace that route).

It's also possible that there's something odd with your machine or browser. Are you able to check from another computer within your network, assuming you have a NAT'ed network connection?

Is the connection intermittent, so that it comes back up? Or is it down for a period of time until you do something to reset your connection? Are the period these blackouts last long, short, are they giving specific errors? Nothing else hiccups in the connection, are all the other websites working well at the same time?

Does your modem have some form of logging that allows you to see if there's a connection issue to your ISP?

Comment: hello,
other websites works well. Other computers cannot access the server aswell on same network. i am getting ping reply successfull aswell.But still cannot access site from browsers. Firefox says "The connection has timed out". And this is happening to my own sites that i host on hostforweb servers. Other sites are working well. Also after some time it starts to work itself. I am totally confused on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that could be happening; for instance:

- Your DNS server could be broken
- Your proxy server, if you're using one, could have issues.
- Your internet provider could lose connectivity to the remote sites.

If it's a DNS issue, you can often work around the issue by either using a different DNS server (e.g. Google's public DNS servers at 4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8), or trying to connect directly to the IP address rather than the hostname.

If it's a proxy server issue - well, try turning off the proxying.

If it's an internet provider issue, that could can often be diagnosed by 'ping' failing to get a response from the site.

Unfortunately, it's rather difficult to give more than a general outline of what could be going wrong, as the error conditions aren't described in any detail. Are connections hanging? Is the connection being reset while loading? Is it 404 or 302ing?

Comment: Hello,On firefox i get The connection has timed out, The server at onnepal.com is taking too long to respond.